# Паскаль, компиляция

Tags: pascal

Не могу прокомилировать, выводит либо ноль либо ошибки

```
K[1]:= 1;
for i:= 2 to N do begin
K[i]:= K[i-1];
if i mod 3 = 0 then
K[i]:= K[i] + K[i div 3]
```

просто надо оформить с var, бегинами и ендами, я не помню как это делать. просто чтобы прошел код

Comment: Добро пожаловать на СО.  Во-первых, код надо писать текстом, а не рисунками и скринами.  Во-вторых, пишите, какие именно ошибки и какой ожидается результат.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: обычно, если не помнят, то берут книжку и вспоминают. Что-нибудь простенькое можно вспомнить через гугл.

Comment: @Эникейщик было бы время...

Comment: за 12 минут, прошедшие с создания вопроса, уже бы все нашлось. А сейчас вопрос закроют и все равно придется искать самостоятельно. А время уже ушло...

Comment: @Эникейщик я над этим сидел больше 12 минут и просто так сюда вопрос не задавал бы

Answer (score 1):

Нет объявления программы:

```
program ProgName;
```

Нет объявления константы:

```
const N = 100;
```

Нет объявления переменных:

```
var
  i: integer;
  K: array[1..N] of integer;
```

Нет начала и конца программы:

```
begin
...
end.
```

В общем, для начала стоит хотя бы школьный учебник информатики в руки взять.

Answer (score 0):

```
program Test;

var
    i, N : integer;
    K :  array[1..100] of integer;
begin

    K[1]:= 1;
    N := 10;

    for i:= 2 to N do begin
        K[i]:= K[i-1];
        if i mod 3 = 0 then
        K[i]:= K[i] + K[i div 3];
       Writeln(K[i]);
    end;

end.
```

Comment: Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "identifier K" found

Comment: Ответ подкорректировал.

Извините, а на занятия по паскалю Вы ходили? Я имею в виду - хотя бы раз.

Comment: Ну что за бесконечный буллинг здесь. Да, простейшее задание, да, решается даже не думая. На занятия ходили. Все учебные годы, начиная с пятого класса я был отличником. У меня были весомые причины чтобы загрузить это сюда, о чем я не раз в комментариях отписал.